# Failed to update datatable after Begin/End Edit

Tags: vb.net

I am using following code to edit my record in datatable.  It does not update the record.

```
Dim drCurrent As DataRow
drCurrent = DbResultDataSet.tblResult.Rows(0)
MsgBox(drCurrent.Item("PaperID"))
drCurrent.BeginEdit()
drCurrent.Item("PaperID") = "433"
drCurrent.EndEdit()
TblResultTableAdapter.Update(DbResultDataSet.tblResult)
```

Please advise what is wrong.
thanks
Furqan